# Gradle Exclude or add reference for JAR file hard included inside library classes.jar

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm running into some trouble with a library I included into my project: 
At the beginning it was just a conflicting dependencies issue that I resolved by excluding 
`support-v4` which is the commonly shared module.

The problem is that one of those `lbsLib-release` seems to have been built with a plain `.jar` file inside of the root project before the developer build.

By running `./gradlew app:dependencies` I verified that the dependency is not referenced in the build graph.

And I found this `support-v4` embedded into the `classes.jar` located 
at : **`app/build/intermedites/exploded-aar/MyQaaAndroid/lbsLib-release/unspecified/classes.jar/`** as you can see on the picture below:

[image]

I can't rebuild the project myself because it is not an open-sourced lib, so there is two problem:

1. If I add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'` to the `build.gradle` a `multiple dex file` error is thrown at build time so the library is referenced twice.

   ```
   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackState;
   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
   ```

   `
2. If I remove all libs which require `support-v4` it throws a missing dependencies error at the application runtime.

So I would like to know if it is possible to exclude this `.jar` file from the build or to make the others libs depends on the `lbsLib-release` embedded `support-v4` `.jar`.

```
compile (project(':lbsLib-release')) {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

compile ('com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:2.0.4'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: If you're including lbsLib-release via a `compile project` directive, then don't you have the source code to it?

Comment: nope it is an *.aar file

Comment: Try doing that `exclude module` bit in the submodule's build.gradle, where you're including the .aar, and not in the top-level, where you're including the submodule.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `resolutionStrategy` ([API reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)) at root `build.gradle`.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    configurations.all((Closure) {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2' // your version of support library
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At [Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility) it easy as `exclude module: 'support-v4'`

example

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.commonsware.cwac:camera-v9:0.5.4') {
      exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}
```